# Entities and the adapter pattern

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipse-rcp

I was wondering what would be the right to go: I have an eclipse rcp application which uses some JPA entities. Now I've would love to use the adapter pattern, which is provided through the `IAdapterFactory` and the `IAdaptable` interface. According to this [article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_IAdaptable_and_IAdapterFactory%3F) my entity has to implement the `IAdaptable` interface but I want to have clean entities and I also do not want write stupid ContentProvider. My question: Do I have any other choice then using ContentProvider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Look at this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_IAdaptable_and_IAdapterFactory%3F)

They say that it is not strictly necessary to implement `IAdaptable`.

It is also possible to do this

```
IAdapterManager manager = Platform.getAdapterManager();
... = manager.getAdapter(object, IResource.class);
```

e.g. `WorkbenchLabelProvider` uses `org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.getAdapter()` which checks if object is `IAdaptable` later uses `IAdapterManager`.

`IAdapterManager` manages `IAdapterFactories`. Adapter factories can be registered programatically using the `registerAdapters` method. Alternatively, they can be registered declaratively using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters` extension point.